# How would a difference in electron and proton charge be detectable in astronomy?

Tags: cosmology, electrons, charge, universe, protons

How would a deviation in neutrality of matter affect astronomy?

Obviously this would introduce a lot of repulsive force but how, exactly, would that affect the universe?

If the repulsive force was small enough that the astronomical phenomena we know could still exist, how would it affect them?

If not, what other astronomical phenomena would exist?

Comment: I attached my attempt at an answer below, but I am curious to know what other people think. I'm sure there are a lot of interesting possibilities I'm missing, and also quite possibly mistakes in my answer.

Comment: As the electron and proton charge are exactly equal, why bother?

Answer (score 1):

*Below, I use $ n\!\downarrow $ to mean $ 10^{-n} $.*

To give an idea of how extreme the results of a slight deviation from neutrality would be: A deviation of $ 7\!\downarrow\! $ (1 in 10 million) would not be detectable at all. This is because our eyeballs would shoot apart with 10 times the force of an elephant gun:
$$
 q_\text{eyeball} = \frac{m_\text{eyeball} N_A e}{p} \cdot \delta
  \approx \frac{3\!\downarrow\! 7.5 \cdot 23\!\uparrow\! 6.0 \cdot 19\!\downarrow\! 1.6}{1.8} \cdot 7\!\downarrow\! \
  \approx 5\!\downarrow\! 4.0\ \text{C}
$$ where $ p \approx 1.8 $ is the number of nucleons per electrons. The electric repulsive force would be:

$$
 F = \frac{kq^2}{r^2}
  = \frac{9\!\uparrow\! 9.0 \cdot (5\!\downarrow\! 4.0)^2}{(2\!\downarrow\! 6.3)^2}
  = \frac{9\!\uparrow\! 9.0 \cdot 10\!\downarrow\! 4.0^2}{4\!\downarrow\! 6.3^2}
  = 4\!\uparrow 3.7\ \text{N}
$$

Even much smaller deviations would make the eyeballs themselves explode.

Now let's calculate the deviation required to break up an astronomical body with mass $m$. This will occur when gravitational acceleration is less than the acceleration caused by the electric field:
\begin{align*}
 a_G = G\frac{m}{r^2} &< k\frac{q}{r^2} \cdot \frac{p}{N_A e} \cdot \delta = E \frac{p}{N_A e} \cdot \delta = a_E \\
 Gm &< kq \cdot \frac{p}{N_A e} \cdot \delta \\
 Gm &< k mN_Ae/p \cdot \frac{p}{N_A e} \cdot \delta \\
 G &< k \cdot \delta \\
 21\!\downarrow\! 7.4 &< \delta \\
\end{align*}

So, irrespective of mass or atomic composition, astronomical bodies would not exist if deviation was greater than $21\!\downarrow\! 7.4\ e$.

Comment: most clever exposition! the imagery is vivid...